# on-premise TFS to VSO issues using OpsHub 1.2.0.000

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, opshub

I have been trying to migrate our on premise TFS to Visual Studio Online for a few months but never been able to successfully do a full migration.  I have tried various ways going from TFS 2012, upgrading to TFS 2013, creating a VM within Azure to migrate the data but whatever I do it runs to slow to migrate the data.  The migration keeps stopping at 445 changsets with a failure "LabelType_Entity@@2@@445 Error - OH-SCM-009: Error occurred while sync. TF400733: The request has been cancelled: The request has exceeded request timeout, please try again."

Also at what point can I’m move the users to Visual Studio Online as its going to take weeks to migrate the source code and we can’t enforce a code freeze for that period of time.  If the migration does run successfully can the migration be performed again to reflect any changes within the on-premise TFS and will this run quicker as its not migrating the entirety of TFS again?

Many Thanks

Comment: IS this still a problem? Microsoft recently announced it's working on a full fidelity solution which allows you to upload a full collection backup and import it as a VS-Team-Services account. If you're still having problems I suggest you hold out for that to be released. The OpsHub tool has issues with certain check-ins (especially merges) where it can take forever to run. The Paid version of the migration utility can resume when it's done to upload the remaining changes as long as no destructive change has happened in the mean time (destroy).